# Google AMP Cache - hot to force loading index.html from cache?

Tags: caching, http2, http-caching, google-amp

Is there any way how to force loading main homepage (index.html) to load from AMP Cache?

I have all images loaded from Cache according to manual: https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview

But in DevTools audit there is still an error for the homepage (not being served through http/2 - from the cache)
[image: DevTools-Audit]

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure exactly what you mean but think you may be misunderstanding the point of the AMP cache.

The Google AMP Cache is not like a CDN (Content Delivery Network) that always sits in front of your site, though in certain instances it acts like one.

The Google AMP Cache is automatically populated by Google when it crawls your site. Any searches on Google while on mobile will then serve your AMP pages, rather than your normal pages, and will also serve them from the Google AMP cache rather than from your domain. This is done for a number of reasons, but primarily to create the “instant loading” effect that AMP gives when loaded from Google Search results (aka Search Engine Results Page or SERP). In this case the whole page including the index page is served from the Google AMP Cache.

Other sites and domains can also decide to display AMP pages instead of your HTML pages if they want, and can decide to serve them from the Google AMP cache, from their own AMP cache (though, other than Google, only [Cloudflare have implemented their own AMP Cache](https://amp.cloudflare.com) AFAIK) or directly from your home page (in which case there is no cache used). Twitter for example automatically replaces links with their AMP equivalents but loads from the real domain so is fast (due to AMP) but not “instant” (like it is in the Google Search Results).

So you, as a site owner, don’t decide when to use the AMP Cache - the calling application (e.g. Google SERPS, Twitter) decides that. And if the calling app/page doesn’t use an AMP Cache, then it is served directly from your domain and therefore whatever technology your domain supports (e.g. HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2). You can of course give out the AMP Cache URL instead of your real one if you want.

You seem to suggest you have altered your page to replace all images and the like with references to the AMP cache - is that so? If so that sounds like a bad idea, as the cache is loaded from your site which now depends on the cache, which is loaded from your site, which is... etc.